# CardView rounded corner overwrites with child view:android

Tags: java, android, cardview

[image]

Its works on lollipop and higher version.
Issue face in Android version 4.4.2 (KitKat).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because lollipop and above android version give padding natively but below to lollipop it's not giving padding so you really need is to disable that behavior using `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` and give padding as you want that apply in all version same(*give padding equal to corner radius value*).

Comment: Giving padding equal to corner radius value will not match to design.

Comment: then give as you want just don't forget to use `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`